# Rails - How to use Validate Uniqueness to store Radio Button Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

given the models:

Question & QuestionAnswers (question_id)

The user can vote on a QuestionAnswer by selecting a radio button. they can therefore only make one vote per question. I want the user to be able to change there vote while not allowing two votes.

What is the right way in Rails, with perhaps model validations. to allow users to revote but in the process not allow two votes... removing the previous vote?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RESTful way to do this is to make a controller for QuestionAnswers with a create and update action.

When they are first selecting the answer.. the form points to the create action.

When they've given an answer, make a form that points to the update for that QuestionAnswer.